# An increasing decreasing sequence

Tags: knowledge, number-sequence, sequence

In math, there are all kinds of sequences

1545, 1218, 1071, 921, 851, 832, 799, 793, 774, 745, ...  is (the start of) such as sequence

What is the best number?

Note:
Even in math things change, so this question needs an answer quick. I assume that this is no problem; that here at Puzzling Stack Exchange we have the best solvers of the best questions.

Hint

> Bobble has been so kind to improve my question, but I fear that has not made the question earlier. So, to finish his work: Mathematics is of course also with a capital. In addition, there is no math tag for a reason. I even left out the number sequence tag (though that is debatable: There not really a pattern. And though there is a next element, I did not ask for it)